# Prestashop: how to limit a voucher to products that are not already discounted?

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop

I see it's a common issue but maybe there is some newer way to solve I don't know, but I really hope though. Maybe some code modification.

It's quite obvious that the merchant should be able to create a voucher and have the option to not apply it to products themselves already discounted. That seems not the case with prestashop.

For now, the only way I can think of, is to put the discounted products on a special frontend-menu-hidden fake category, and then assign the voucher to all the categories but the fake one. Basically, working out the logic upside down. Quite crazy, indeed.

So, is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the newly released 1.7, but in 1.6 you have to make the hidden category you're suggesting.

Here's a quick way to get the sale status on all your products:

```
SELECT 
p.id_product,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ps_specific_price WHERE id_product = p.id_product AND id_cart = 0 AND id_customer = 0 AND ((`from` <= NOW() AND `to` >= NOW()) OR (`from` = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" AND `to` >= NOW()) OR (`from` = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" AND `to` = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"))) on_sale
FROM ps_product p
ORDER BY p.id_product
```

Please note that *id_shop* (multishop), *currency* and *country* is not taken into consideration.